# nodejs no reconoce .find() de moongose

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Tengo este error al tratar retornanar la informacion de mi colencion con un arreglo pero, surje un error con la funcion Employee.find().

**'Error de la consola'**

```
/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/src/controllers/employees.controller.js:8
   const employees = await Employee.find()
                                    ^
```

```
TypeError: Employee.find is not a function
    at employeesCtrl.getEmployees (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/src/controllers/employees.controller.js:8:37)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at logger (/home/edgar/Desktop/Proyectos/mean-employees/server/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**employees.controller.js**

```
const employeesCtrl = {};

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Employee = require('../models/Employee');

employeesCtrl.getEmployees = async (req, res) => {
   const employees = await Employee.find()
   res,json(employees)
};
employeesCtrl.createEmployee = (req, res) => {
    res.send('create employees');
};
employeesCtrl.getEmployee = (req, res) => {};
employeesCtrl.editEmployee = (req, res) => {};
employeesCtrl.deleteEmployee = (req, res) => {};

module.exports = employeesCtrl;
```

**Employee.js**

```
const { Schema, model} = require('mongoose');

const employeesNewSchema = new Schema ({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    position: {type: String, required: true},
    office: {type: String, required: true},
    salary: {type: Number, required: true}
},{
    timestamps: true,
    versionKey: false
});

model.exports = model('Employee', employeesNewSchema);
```

Comment: ```.find()``` te devolverá todos los resultados, si embargo mongo solo devuelve algunos y tenes que ir recorriendolos, esto se llaman *cursores*, sin embargo el error dice que ```.find()``` no es una función, revisa como es que exportar el modelo, haz probado guardando los datos? Para ver si en realidad ```Employee``` hace la conexión con la BD

Comment: si, pero ya encontre mi error en employees estaba exportando mal, aun asi gracias por comentar

Comment: Que bueno que hayas resuelto tu error, y los iento no me di cuenta del error de sintaxis

Answer (score 0):

Jajaja lo siento chicos, pero yo ya encontre mi error, en employees yo puse.

```
model.exports = model('Employee', employeesNewSchema);
```

***y era***

```
module.exports = model('Employee', employeesNewSchema);
```